# How do you declare/make "QBarSet" to be an array?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to the QT GUI/Widget and classes and pointer. I had an assignment which requires me to make a bar graph using QT Widget. However, I'm trying to implement an array in the code to be neater.

This is part of the code:

```
    //assign names to the set of bars used
    QBarSet *set0 = new QBarSet("Jane");
    QBarSet *set1 = new QBarSet("John");
    QBarSet *set2 = new QBarSet("Axel");
    QBarSet *set3 = new QBarSet("Mary");
    QBarSet *set4 = new QBarSet("Samantha");

    //assign values for each bar
    *set0 << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4 << 5 << 6;
    *set1 << 5 << 3 << 6 << 4 << 2 << 7;
    *set2 << 3 << 5 << 8 << 10 << 8 << 5;
    *set3 << 5 << 6 << 7 << 3 << 4 << 5;
    *set4 << 9 << 7 << 5 << 3 << 1 << 2;

    //add all sets of data to the chart as a whole
    //1. Bar Chart
    QBarSeries *series = new QBarSeries();
    //2. Stacked Bar Chart
    series->append(set0);
    series->append(set1);
    series->append(set2);
    series->append(set3);
    series->append(set4);
```

As you can see above, I'm trying to make the `set` variable to be an array. How do I do that?

Comment: You mean `QBarSet *setArray[5];`?

Comment: @Limas Nursalim: The following should work `set1->append(QList<double>{5.,3.,6.,4.,2.,7.})`. By the way a `QVector<double>{5.,3.,6.,4.,2.,7.}.toList()` is an alternative, if you have to use a `QVector`.